# Injetar facebook api no controller de AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, api

Esta função é chamada por um `ng-click` em um botão na minha view, mas não está retornando nada no console.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
$scope.shareContent = function(){
    window.fbAsyncInit  = function(){
        FB.init({
            appID   : '1565222510432359',
            status  : true,
            xfbml   : true,
            version : 'v2.3'
        });

        var obj  = {
            method  : 'feed',
            name    : 'Teste',
            link    : 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
            caption : 'teste exemplo'
        }

        FB.ui(obj,function(response){}); 
    };
}
```

Comment: Você definiu algo para ser escrito no console em algum momento? Não vejo nada no seu código.. Tente isso: `FB.ui(obj,function(response){  console.log(response)  }); `

Comment: Esse `FB.ui`, era pra abrir um share box e não abriu nada. O que estou tentando fazer é abrir um share Box

Comment: Então a sua questão diferente, pois você questionou por que não havia nada no console. Você está usando algum plugin de angular para integrar o facebook? Ou está tentando uso bruto da api deles?

Comment: estou tentando normalmente, sem plugin. O meu questionamento de não aparecer algo no console, foi que pro sim ou pro não, deveria surgir algum erro ou algo do tipo.

Comment: não necessariamente, pois você não deixou explicito isso, o que ele forneceria de erro seria se algo entrasse em conflito com o angular em geral, como um erro de injeção, por exemplo. Mas sobre o fb, eu recomendo que trabalhe com algum plugin já existente, pois eles facilitam MUITO o fluxo e deixam seu código mais simples de gerenciar, veja este por exemplo: https://github.com/Ciul/angular-facebook

Comment: eu cheguei a ver esse plugin, é muito pro que tenho que fazer, eu apenas quero carregar o sdk do facebook e mostrar um box de share com conteúdo dinâmico.

Comment: Ai não sei como te ajudar, confesso que nunca fiz desse modo, mas segundo o próprio facebook, acho que você vai precisar mudar o modo como está trabalhando, veja: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/howto/angularjs